# how to hide softkeyboard using androidviewclient

Tags: androidviewclient

I am UI and in that in edittext I type and then click button.  The softkeyboard stays popped up.  Actually before clicking button I want to hide keyboard.  How to do it ?

Regards,

miten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(R.id.value).getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

KEYCODE_BACK works for the phones I use (not emulators).